# Typescript project reference resolves the wrong path

Tags: typescript

I have a project reference to a common library using typescript ^5.0.4

It sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, but I'm not sure what is causing the issue. Building the main project builds the lib so they seem to be connected but the import paths it creates seem to be incorrect.

Folder structure is as follows:

```
/
├── lib/
│   └── tsconfig.json
│  
└── server/
    └── tsconfig.json
```

Server references lib
Upon running I get this:
"Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/workspace/server/lib' imported from /workspace/server/dist/modules/user.js"

server tsconfig is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es2020", 
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, 
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "lib": [
    "es2020",
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../lib"
    }
  ]
}
```

and lib config is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020", 
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, 
    "strict": true,
    "declaration": true, 
    "declarationMap": true,
    "rootDir": ".",   
    "composite": true, 
    "outDir": "./build"
  },
  "references": []  // * Any project that is referenced must itself have a `references` array (which may be empty).
}
```

Is there something I'm missing?